# Prove this inequality for all integers $m>2$

Tags: inequality

Prove this inequality for all integers $m$:

$$∑_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1-n^{2α-1}}{n^{\alpha}} > \frac{1-(m+1)^{2α-1}}{(m+1)^{\alpha}}$$

for all $0<α<1/2$ and $m>2$.

Comment: $$(1-n^{2\alpha-1})/n^\alpha=1/n^{\alpha} - n^{\alpha-1}$$ Now use the formula for geometric series.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: But the summation is with respect to $n$ not to $α$

Comment: This is false in general. Here is an easy counterexample for $\alpha=0, m=3:$ The LHS is $(1-\frac{1}{2}) + (1-\frac{1}{3})= \frac{7}{6}$ and the RHS is $1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$. Numerical computations show that for almost all $\alpha<1/2$ and $m>2$ the inequality should be reversed, i.e. the function
$$
f(\alpha, m) = \frac{1-(m+1)^{2\alpha-1}} {(m+1)^{\alpha}} - 
\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1-n^{2\alpha-1}}{n^\alpha}$$
is negative. As it stands it seems only valid for $\alpha<1/2$ and $m=2.$

Comment: @gammatester: It become true if I remove the value $α=0$,

Comment: It can't be. The right hand side, $$\frac{1}{(m+1)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{(m+1)^{1-\alpha}},$$ tends to $0$ for $m\to\infty$, but the left hand side is positive and increasing.

Comment: @DanielFischer: So the inequality should be reversed.

Comment: No, reversing does not make it true: for $\alpha=0.25, m=2$ the LHS is $0.24629$ and the RHS is $0.32114,\;$ see my first comment.

Comment: @gammatester: Ok I have changed the question and I seeking a proof.